# How should I treat return value of command or function? As string or integer?

Tags: bash

I am learning bash.
I learned return value of command or function is an integer value.
I wonder whether I should treat it as integer explicitly,

```
declare -i return_value
bash some_function
return_value=$?
if (( return_value == 1 )); then
  exit 1
fi
```

or treat it as string value.

```
bash some_function
return_value="$?"
if [[ "$return_value" == "1" ]]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

Please tell me your answer or comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: As an integer. either as you have or `if [[ $return_value -eq 1 ]]` (you don't need to quote variables within `[[...]]` (everywhere else, you do) when in doubt , double-quote it.

Comment: @David C. Rankin : Thank you for your comment. I agree with you. Quoting LHS in [[ ]] is not necessary. Its my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an integer, so you should treat it as such. However, it's not necessary (and uncommon) to declare the variable in advance.

It's really a matter of preference but I'd probably go with this:

```
bash some_function
return_value=$?
if [ $return_value -eq 1 ]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

simply because you know it's a return code, so you don't need to be careful about quoting or use an extended test `[[`. Using `-eq` as opposed to `=` communicates the fact you're working with an integer.

You might also want to consider this option, depending on the context:

```
if ! some_function; then
  exit 1
fi
```

This is slightly different, as it doesn't differentiate between non-zero exit codes, but it may do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

[Exit codes and exit status are integers](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html), but in bash [variables are untyped](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html), so you may choose to treat them as either strings or integers.

I prefer to treat them as integers, and I often see an idiomatic construction with `$?` and integer comparison operators, like so:

```
some_function
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    # handle error here
fi
```